# AWS REST API Query

Tags: amazon-web-services, api

How to authenticate against AWS to make API query ?

```
https://iam.amazonaws.com/?Action=ListAttachedUserPolicies&UserName=ja&Version=2010-05-08&accesskey
```

and getting:

```
<Code>MissingAuthenticationToken</Code>
<Message>Request is missing Authentication Token</Message>
```

Comment: You have to pass an access key...  what did you try ? which command are you passing ?

Comment: I already passed access key, i need to get list of attached user policies (see link i posted in question)

Comment: This is usually related to requesting a URL that doesn't exist .. make sure you're using the correct HTTP method and path to a valid resource.

Comment: i collected that link from AWS docs:https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_ListAttachedUserPolicies.html

Comment: From [Welcome page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html): "Requests must be signed using an **access key ID** and **a secret access key**. " As far as I can guess from the few you gave, you're passing only an accesskey (in a strange form, I can't tell if accesskey is a placeholder here or just the parameter name with the value stripped down)

Comment: And you probably need to read this also: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html

Comment: yes, accesskey is parameter, but when specify secret then getting :<Code>MalformedQueryString</Code>
<Message>Keys may not contain +</Messag

Answer (score 2):

Got it working by aws curl https://github.com/okigan/awscurl

```
awscurl --service iam 'https://iam.amazonaws.com/?Action=ListUsers&Version=2010-05-08'
```

Comment: I Really wonder what that bring up over aws cli... This whole Q/A sounds useless for anyone but you for me

Comment: tried to find a way to get IAM roles from python, not using subprocesses, and hoped  awscurl could be run from python script-from shell it works fine but from python again got missing authentication (using reguests)

Comment: Why don't you use boto3 in python, the official aws python sdk?

Comment: it doesn't have all capability as aws cli/aws url

Comment: Sounds utterly strange as aws cli is a python program... https://github.com/aws/aws-cli

Comment: After re-reading it I was thinking king about botocore, the low level interface behind bouo3 to make raw requests: https://github.com/boto/botocore

Answer (score 0):

The referred documentation from the question 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_ListAttachedUserPolicies.html

has this example of a request:

```
https://iam.amazonaws.com/?Action=ListAttachedUserPolicies
&UserName=Alice
&Version=2010-05-08
&AUTHPARAMS
```

AUTHPARAMS are explained 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-2.html

(version 4 is preferred)
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-calculate-signature.html

So you have to calculate a digest from the request together with your secret key and you have to do it exactly as it is explained in the documentation - which means be careful about every letter including spaces.